# Killing processes in ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python, multiprocessing, executor, process-pool

I am using Python's `ProcessPoolExecutor` to run multiple processes in parallel and process them as any of them finishes. Then I look at their output and as soon as **at least one of them** gives satisfying answer I want to exit the program.

However, this is not possible since upon calling `pool.shutdown(wait=False)` I will have to wait for all active tasks in the `pool` to finish before I can exit my script.

Is there a way to kill all the remaining active children and exit?
Also, is there a better way to stop as soon as at least one child returns the answer we are waiting for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is not quite clear, but executors strike me as the wrong tool entirely.

multiprocessing.Pool seems much more suitable, and allows doing exactly what you're asking for: you can iterate on `imap_unordered` (or `apply_async` and poll the results), and once you have what you were looking for just `terminate()` the pool then `join()` it.

Comment: thanks! will `terminate()` also kill all submitted process?

Comment: That is, in fact, the entire point of `terminate`. The alternative is `close()` which prevents new tasks from being submitted and instructs worker to exit as they finish their tasks, but `terminate()` stops the workers even if they're mid-job.

Comment: from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed
exc = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)
processes = [exc.submit(job, arg) for job, args in jobs_tuple]
for job in as_completed(processes):
    if job.result() == 'meets_a_condition':
        break
exc.shutdown(wait=False)
`